# extracting information from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary response from a Flickr api request and it's description looks like this:

```
self.userInfo: {
"_text" = "\n\n";
person =     {
    "_text" = "\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n";
    description =         {
    };
    iconfarm = 0;
    iconserver = 0;
    id = "83943196@N02";
    ispro = 0;
    location =         {
    };
    "mbox_sha1sum" =         {
        "_text" = 7b61c5d24f12345678be82c31234567830540;
    };
    mobileurl =         {
        "_text" = "http://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=12345678";
    };
    nsid = "12345678@N02";
    "path_alias" = "";
    photos =         {
        "_text" = "\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t";
        count =             {
            "_text" = 2;
        };
        firstdate =             {
            "_text" = 12345678;
        };
        firstdatetaken =             {
            "_text" = "2012-08-01 12:46:38";
        };
        views =             {
            "_text" = 0;
        };
    };
    photosurl =         {
        "_text" = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/12345678@N02/";
    };
    profileurl =         {
        "_text" = "http://www.flickr.com/people/12345678@N02/";
    };
    realname =         {
        "_text" = "Me TheUser";
    };
    timezone =         {
        label = "Pacific Time (US & Canada); Tijuana";
        offset = "-08:00";
    };
    username =         {
        "_text" = metheuser;
    };
};
stat = ok;
}
```

I'm having truoble figuring out how to extract the realname value into a NSString.

I've tried:

```
NSString * temp = [self.userInfo valueForKey:@"realname"];
NSLog (@"FL: nameOfSignedInUser. nameself.userInfo: %@", temp.debugDescription);
```

but that comes back as nil.

thank you!

Comment: It looks like the `realname` object is nested in the `person` object, have you tried retrieving `person` as a dictionary, then getting `realname` from that?

Comment: yeah,thanks for the tip. I checked the count and its 3. I guess first is test, second is person and third is stat

Comment: When in doubt, iterate over all the root object's keys and objects to see what you have.  I used a similar process when dealing with arbitrary webservice return values parsed from XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *name = [self.userInfo valueForKeyPath:@"person.realname._text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *realName = [[[self.userInfo objectForKey:@"person"] objectForKey:@"realname"] objectForKey:@"_text"];
```

Comment: Damit; I'm sure your answer didn't look like that when I answered mine (which is identical!).  I will delete mine...

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry, I deleted and changed it. I didn't see what other's posted. EJV is really the correct answer here. I've never used `valueForKeyPath:` good to know.

Comment: yeah, I don't even see it in the NSArray class reference document. Only in NSKeyValueCoding Protocol Reference